# excel vba need date as integer value like in excels datevalue()

Tags: excel, date, vba

I try to get a date that is available as a string in "DD.MM.YYYY" fashion, changed to the value that excel normally applies to dates.

I tried `CDbl(strDate)` as was suggested a lot. But instead of giving back 42023 as `=DATVALUE("19.01.2015")` does, in my case it returns 19012015.

```
strDate = "19.01.2015"
MsgBox CDbl(strDate)
```

How can I change that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the full-stops (periods) to slashes, then convert to date, then convert to double.
Watch out for regional variations in date formatting though - not sure how it will affect the result - test with a date such as 01/02/2015 and see if it returns 1st Feb or 2nd Jan.

```
Sub test()

    Dim strdate As String

    strdate = "19.01.2015"
    MsgBox CDbl(CDate(Replace(strdate, ".", "/")))

End Sub
```